# Convert String into ArrayList<Integer> with stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to convert String into ArrayList.

```
String accountNumberValue = "151616165132132";
```

I try to do this but its look like hardcoded with double parsing `char` to `String` and `Integer`:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> accNumArray = accountNumberValue.chars()
                         .map((s)-> Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s)))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any easy way?

Comment: an arraylist of what? and in what format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
List<Integer> result=accountNumberValue
                     .chars()   //Get IntStream from a string with char codes
                     .map(Character::getNumericValue) //Map to the actual int
                     .boxed()  //Box the intstream 
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());  //Collect
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single parsing by using `split`:

```
List<Integer> accNumArray = 
               Arrays.stream(accountNumberValue.split(""))
                     .map(Integer::parseInt)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not much of an improvement, but you could use `Character#getNumericValue`:

```
List<Integer> accNumArray = accountNumberValue.chars()
    .map(c -> new Integer(Character.getNumericValue(c)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I saw your answer after I posted mine. This is pretty  much the same but won't work because chars() return IntStream  so in order to collect it you need to 'box' it first. If you test it doesn't even compile